# How to implement a shareable link system for personal "Favorite Items List" in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I need to implement a frontend only (preferably) application using  Angular2+, and one of the required features is, the user must be able to save in it's local storage (eg. cookies) a list of it's favorite items in the website. The problem is that they also must be able to share a link to this list. I'm new to web dev, so i have no idea how to implement such feature.

I'm using Angular 2 in the project. It is a very simple website, no user account/login, just data pulled from a third-party API, which then shows items to users, and they can mark some as favorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a web page to be able to share a state using a url without any backend, you can pass a **state** in your query params.

In your case, since you want a list of items, you need to pass a list of an `id` you can use to fetch the items from the third-party API and reconstruct the same page data.

Check for query parameters on page load, and create a link to the page with the corresponding query params.

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'kb-example-page',
  templateUrl: './example-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example-page.component.scss']
})
export class ExamplePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private examplePageService: ExamplePageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const queryParams = this.activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams;

    // get the list of items
    // if queryParam exists, returns an array
    // if not, parsedItems will be undefined
    const parsedItemIds = queryParams &&
      queryParams.items &&
      queryParams.items.split(',');

    if (parsedItemIds) {
      this.fetchData(parsedItemIds);
    }
}

  createShareableLink(items: any[]) {
    // create a list of item ids in a queryParam syntax
    const itemsQueryParam = 'items=' + items.map((item) => item.id).join(',');

    // create a link to this page with the
    // queryParams representing the items
    return `${ SITE_URL }?${ itemsQueryParam }`;
  }

  fetchData(itemIds: string[]) {
    this.examplePageService
      .fetchItems(items)
      .subscribe(() => /* initialize the page with the data */);
  }
}
```

### Dealing with large URLs

If you want to make sure the URl is not huge, you can use a URL shortener service like [this one](https://developers.rebrandly.com/docs).

This will create a link to the shortener service site, that will redirect to your site with all the query params in the url

Comment: @EmanuelKozerski Also added a section on how to shorten the URL

Comment: Oh sure, thank you. Also not much used to StackOverflow. I'm accepting this as the right answer because it seems the most complete.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see is to genereate an link to an end point of your web site with an array as queryparam (splitting your array with ',' ie: 'item1,item2,...)
In this array you will put the list of favorite items.

Then in this endPoint you gather the queryparam and display the favorite items list:

```
itemIds: string[]
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(
        (routerEvent: RouterEvent) => {
            if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.itemIds= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('itemIds').split(',');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Cool, thx for that. I guess it would be a very large URL if the user's list is big